# Query table with condition (one to many relation)

Tags: sql

There is a table with column ‘FileType’ and It can have values from 1 to 10. It has one to many relation.

How to query this table to get rows where FileType is not equal to 1 and 2 but at least contains 4.

Table A

```
ID - File Type

1  - 4
1  - 1
1  - 10
2  - 1
2  - 4
3  - 4
3  - 5
```

Query should only return ID 3

I have tried where clause

Where FileType = 4 AND FileType <> 1 AND FileType <> 2 AND FileType IN (3,5,6,7,8,9,10)

Comment: Can you reformulate this more clear, please: "to get rows where FileType is not equal to 1 and 2 but at least contains 4"?

Comment: How can i check for at least 4

Answer (score 1):

This should do it

```
select Id
from TableA
where FileType = 4
and Id not in (select Id from TableA where FileType = 1 or FileType = 2)
```

Comment: Is tableA in inner query is same as main TableA?

Comment: what if TableA is part of INNER JOIN and TableB is part of select clause.

Comment: @user1263981 I don't understand what TableB is.  I need a little more context/information here.